# std::vector of functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, stdvector

I want a std::vector to contain some functions, and that more functions can be added to it in realtime. All the functions will have a prototype like this:

void name(SDL_Event *event);

I know how to make an array of functions, but how do I make a std::vector of functions? I've tried this:

```
std::vector<( *)( SDL_Event *)> functions;

std::vector<( *f)( SDL_Event *)> functions;

std::vector<void> functions;

std::vector<void*> functions;
```

But none of them worked. Please help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using a typedef:

```
typedef void (*SDLEventFunction)(SDL_Event *);
std::vector<SDLEventFunction> functions;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
std::vector<void ( *)( SDL_Event *)> functions;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like boost then then you could do it like this:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <vector>

void f1(SDL_Event *event)
{
    // ...
}

void f2(SDL_Event *event)
{
    // ...
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::function<void(SDL_Event*)> > functions;
    functions.push_back(boost::bind(&f1, _1));
    functions.push_back(boost::bind(&f2, _1));

    // invoke like this:
    SDL_Event * event1 = 0; // you should probably use
                            // something better than 0 though..
    functions[0](event1);
    return 0;
}
```